# SyntaxError: missing : after property id when using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

Why do I get the following error when doing the following inside the jQuery validation plugin by bassistance? IMO this should have worked, but I get this:

> SyntaxError: missing : after property id

```
var type = $(this).type; //This is a hidden field in the form 


$("#myForm").validate({

    var type = $(this).type;
    rules: {
        name: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 3,
            maxlength: 51
        },
    },
```

Comment: Like any other jQuery plugin method, you can only pass `key:value` pairs separated by commas inside of the `.validate()` method. The allowed `key`s and their acceptable `value`s are pre-defined by the plugin developer.  I guess you skipped the docs.  http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because the `validate` method accepts object, yet you did not pass an object, try

```
$("#myForm").validate({

type : $(this).type,
rules: {
    name: {
        required: true,
        minlength: 3,
        maxlength: 51
    },
```

Comment: Sure, I will. BTW, I cannot use var type : $(this).type?

Comment: I'm not sure what does the type object needs, i checked out the documentation, but it doesn't have the type key .

Comment: `type` is not a valid option for this plugin.  You can only use options specified by the developer.